# Problemas con estilo de editor de texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Estoy desarrollando un editor de texto básico. Tengo un problema con los botones de bold, italic, underline y strikeThrough: cuando inicio el editor y selecciono todos los estilos estos se ponen de color azul indicando que el texto a escribir va a recibir esos 4 estilos. Cuando quito los estilos estos en algunas ocasiones quedan de color azul indicando que siguen activos pero, en realidad. si escribes en el editor puedes notar que ya estos estilos no se están aplicando.

Dejaré todo el código para ver si alguien tiene idea de qué puede ser:

```js
// Obtener el elemento del editor y el botón de limpiar
const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
const botonLimpiar = document.querySelector('#toolbar button:last-of-type');

// Función para aplicar formato al texto seleccionado
function formato(comando, numero) {
  var condicion = numero

  document.execCommand(comando, false, null);
  resaltarBotones(condicion)


}

// Función para cambiar la fuente del texto seleccionado
function fuente(select) {
  const fuente = select.value;
  document.execCommand('fontName', false, fuente);
}

// Función para cambiar el tamaño del texto seleccionado
function tamano(select) {
  const tamano = select.value;
  document.execCommand('fontSize', false, tamano);
}

// Función para cambiar el color del texto seleccionado
function color(input) {
  const color = input.value;
  document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color);
}

// Función para limpiar el contenido del editor
function limpiar() {
  editor.innerHTML = '';
}

// Función para guardar el contenido del editor en un archivo
function guardar() {
  // Este es solo un ejemplo y no guarda realmente el contenido en un archivo
  const contenido = editor.innerHTML;
  console.log('Contenido guardado: ', contenido);
}

// Agregar un evento de clic al botón de limpiar para llamar a la función limpiar
botonLimpiar.addEventListener('click', limpiar);

function resaltarBotones(numero) {

  if (numero == 1) {

    var botonBold = document.getElementById('btnBold');

    if (document.queryCommandState('bold')) {
      botonBold.classList.add('activo');
      console.log("activo")
    } else {
      botonBold.classList.remove('activo');
      console.log("inactivo")
    }

  }

  if (numero == 2) {

    var botonItalic = document.getElementById('btnItalic');

    if (document.queryCommandState('italic')) {
      botonItalic.classList.add('activo');
      console.log("activo")
    } else {
      botonItalic.classList.remove('activo');
      console.log("inactivo")
    }

  }

  if (numero == 3) {

    var btnUnderline = document.getElementById('btnUnderline');

    if (document.queryCommandState('underline')) {
      btnUnderline.classList.add('activo');
      console.log("activo")
    } else {
      btnUnderline.classList.remove('activo');
      console.log("inactivo")
    }
  }


  if (numero == 4) {

    var btnStrike = document.getElementById('btnStrike');

    if (document.queryCommandState('strikeThrough')) {
      btnStrike.classList.add('activo');
      console.log("activo")
    } else {
      btnStrike.classList.remove('activo');
      console.log("inactivo")
    }

  }

}
```

```css
#toolbar {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 99%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

#toolbar button,
#toolbar select,
#toolbar input[type=color] {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#toolbar button:hover,
#toolbar select:hover,
#toolbar input[type=color]:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#toolbar button:active,
#toolbar select:active,
#toolbar input[type=color]:active {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#toolbar button:focus,
#toolbar select:focus,
#toolbar input[type=color]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #4d90fe;
}

#editor:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#editor {
  width: 99%;
  height: 400px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#toolbar button.activo {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
  <button onclick="editor.focus();formato('bold',1);" id="btnBold"><b>N</b></button>
  <button onclick="editor.focus();formato('italic',2)" id="btnItalic"><i>N</i></button>
  <button onclick="editor.focus();formato('underline',3)" id="btnUnderline"><u>N</u></button>
  <button onclick="editor.focus();formato('strikeThrough',4)" id="btnStrike"><strike>N</strike></button>
  <select onchange="fuente(this)">
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
    <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
    <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
  </select>
  <select onchange="tamano(this)">
    <option value="1">Tamaño 1</option>
    <option value="2">Tamaño 2</option>
    <option value="3">Tamaño 3</option>
    <option value="4">Tamaño 4</option>
    <option value="5">Tamaño 5</option>
    <option value="6">Tamaño 6</option>
    <option value="7">Tamaño 7</option>
  </select>
  <input type="color" onchange="color(this)">
  <button onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button>
  <button onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button>
</div>
<div id="editor" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Probé tu código y no pude reproducir el problema. Además no se marcó nada en azul nunca, creo que te faltó agregar algún CSS. Por otro lado te aviso que `execCommand` está marcado como obsoleto https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/execComman

Comment: Cuando presionas el botón de bold este cambia su color azul indicando que el texto que vas a escribir está negrita

Comment: El problema es que tu editor "no sabe dónde está." Me explico: puedes escribir un párrafo, seleccionar un texto y pulsar el botón de negrita y el texto se pondrá en negrita... pero en cuanto pulses en cualquier otro lugar, el botón de negrita seguirá marcado aunque la zona en la que estés no sea en negrita y no se vaya a escribir en negrita. Una posible solución sería, cada vez que se hace click, detectar los estilos y activar los botones correspondientes. Como puedes ver, esto no es un problema trivial y es el motivo por el que recomendaría usar una herramienta ya creada y con soporte amplio.

Comment: Aparte de eso, esta solución utiliza `queryCommandState` que es una función que se considera obsoleta y que podría perder soporte de forma repentina (se deprecó hace años), por lo que no es recomendable utilizarla. Puedes leer más sobre esto en la [página de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandState)